# SQL Server avoid repeat same joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I´m doing the query below where I´m repeating the same joins multiple times, there is a better way to do it? (SQL Server Azure)

Ex.

```
    Table: [Customer]
    [Id_Customer] | [CustomerName]
    1             | Tomy
    ...

    Table: [Store]
    [Id_Store] | [StoreName]
    1          | SuperMarket
    2          | BestPrice
    ...
    
    Table: [SalesFrutes]
    [Id_SalesFrutes] | [FruteName] | [Fk_Id_Customer] | [Fk_Id_Store]
    1                | Orange      | 1                | 1
    ...

    Table: [SalesVegetable]
    [Id_SalesVegetable] | [VegetableName] | [Fk_Id_Customer] | [Fk_Id_Store]
    1                   | Pea             | 1                | 2
    ...

Select * From [Customer] as C
left join [SalesFrutes] as SF on SF.[Fk_Id_Customer] = C.[Id_Customer]
left join [SalesVegetable] as SV on SV.[Fk_Id_Customer] = C.[Id_Customer]
left join [Store] as S1 on S1.[Id_Store] = SF.[Fk_Id_Store]
left join [Store] as S2 on S1.[Id_Store] = SV.[Fk_Id_Store]
```

In my real case, I have many [Sales...] to Join with [Customer] and many other tables similar to [Store] to join to each [Sales...]. So it starts to scale a lot the number on joins repeating. There is a better way to do it?

Bonus question: I do like also to have FruteName, VegetableName, StoreName, and each Food table name under the same column.

```
The Expected Result is:
[CustomerName] | [FoodName] | [SalesTableName] | [StoreName]
Tomy           | Orange     | SalesFrute       | SuperMarket
Tomy           | Pea        | SalesVegetable   | BestPrice
...
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Multiple joins to the same table is very common.  You could simplify things by unioning together your SalesFrutes and SalesVegetable tables.  Splitting those into two tables seems an odd design choice.

Comment: I would second that, things would be very much easie if you joined to a table `sales` in which you had a `type` to indicate what was sold; having separate tables with essentially the same schema and data is your root problem.

Comment: This Sales... was just for the example, in my real scenario they are not equivalent in information.

Comment: The suggested comments and answers are going to be applicable to the information you provide, not what you don't provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on the information provided, I would have suggested the below, to use a `cte` to "fix" the data model and make writing your query easier.

Since you say your real-world scenario is different to the info provided it might not work for you, but could still be applicable if you have say 80% shared columns, you can just use placeholder/null values where relevant for unioning the data sets and still minimise the number of joins eg to your `store` table.

```
with allSales as (
    select Id_SalesFrutes as Id, FruitName as FoodName, 'Fruit' as SaleType, Fk_Id_customer as Id_customer, Fk_Id_Store as Id_Store
    from SalesFruits
    union all
    select Id_SalesVegetable, VegetableName, 'Vegetable', Fk_Id_customer, Fk_Id_Store
    from SalesVegetable
    union all... etc
)
select c.CustomerName, s.FoodName, s.SaleType, st.StoreName
from Customer c
join allSales s on s.Id_customer=c.Id_customer
join Store st on st.Id_Store=s.Id_Store
```

Comment: I´ll try to put all Sales common columns to do the union, thank you